# Creating Separate sheets for different months with same formatting

Tags: excel

I'm trying to figure out a way to duplicate a sheet, but change the dates to the corresponding month.

[image]

In the above image, I have weekdays for the month of April and below each date I have a grouping of PTO, Offsite, or Onsite. I want to be able to duplicate this exact format over to May, counting only weekdays and keeping the grouping below each date. Is there a way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: weekdays only as in M-F? regardless of vacations/holidays? so would it be carrying over WW1 from April to WW1 in May? e.g. WW1 in April starts on April-3rd 2023 and would be carried over to WW1 in May which starts on May-1st 2023 ?

Answer (score 0):

First, you're going to want to use the =workday() function.

Cell A2 = workday($A$1,0,$H$1:$H$7)

A1 = First calendar day of month
H1:H7 = enter any holidays in this range that you want to skip

Cell A6 = workday($A$1,1,$H$1:$H$7)

You're only changing the 2nd variable in the formula for each new date.